# How do I make it so users can instal my test package from the cli?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jasmine

I created a small test program for web applications that uses jasmine, and I'm preparing it for easy downloads. Before installing my package, the user's project should look something like this:

```
myProject/
  app/
  lib/
  ...
```

I want to be able to have the user cd to myProject in the terminal, issue a single command that points to the app and lib folders, and then end up with this:

```
myProject/
  app/
  lib/
    requirejs
  test/
    lib/
    node_modules/
    specs/
    SpecRunner.html
    server.js
  ...
```

app/ should contain the js project files, lib/ should contain all the external js dependencies for the project, and test/lib/ should contain all the external dependencies for the tests. server.js runs with nodejs and depends on apps installed in node_modules/.

What's the best way to go about doing this? I could make a bash script, but I'd rather use a package manager. I'm not sure how I'd do this in bower or npm. And am I right in thinking it's better to have two libs, one for the project and one for testing, rather than one? I know I can declare certain packages as test packages in bower, but it seems like they should live in a separate libraries.

Comment: you can use devDependencies. take a look here https://www.npmjs.org/doc/json.html#devDependencies

Comment: @Irakli Doesn't that just dump my library in the top level node_modules? How would I assign the app/ and lib/ references to my library in package.json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And am I right in thinking it's better to have two libs, one for the project and one for testing, rather than one?

No. The idiomatic way in the npm-verse is to have tests in the same package in the `test` folder. Since bower is based on npm I'd say the same applies there too. If you don't want bower users to have to download test-stuff you should be able to ignore the test folder in the `bower.json` file (according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18245451/1165146)). You should also specify node modules that are only used for tests as `devDependencies`.

Developers who want to run your test should IMO install it directly from source using e.g. `git clone git@github.com/your/repo.git` (and then just run `npm install`). Or simply `npm install x` if it's available on npm. Even if you really want the tests in their own package, I'd still suggest not using a package manager but ask the developer to clone it from the repo into the test folder.

Anyway to answer the question, the following one-liner should work (assuming npm, I'm not too familiar with bower):

```
npm install x-test && mv node_modules/x-test test
```

Comment: Hmm, ok. Still a bit of a longer a process than I'd hoped for, but I guess that's unavoidable. Thanks.