# How can I keep Bower from blowing away my .git directory?

Tags: polymer, bower

I'm developing two Polymer components, which contain bower.json files so that their dependencies can be resolved using bower. One of these components is dependent on the other. Everything works fine, except when I `bower install` in the component which has a dependency on the other component, it blows away the `.git` directory in the other, at which point I have to delete it and re-clone.

I investigated the options available for `.bowerrc` on [the bower website](http://bower.io/docs/config/), but don't see any option related to ignoring directories or files.

I'm tagging this as 'Polymer' related since it may be a flaw in my workflow which other Polymer devs may have run into, but I'm hoping it isn't a limitation of Bower to not ignore such things.

Comment: I don't know anything about bower but maybe this could help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18245394/ignore-in-bowers-bower-json

Comment: How did you define the dependency between the 2 components in your bower.json?