# ignore file in bower doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, gulp, bower

I have 2 packages :

- bootstrap
- boostrap-tour

But bootstrap-tour package is like that :

```
Build
    CSS
       boostrap-tour.css
       boostrap-tour-standalone.css
    JS
       boostrap-tour.js
       boostrap-tour-standalone.js
```

boostrap-tour-standalone is a problem because it s the same file that boostrap but in a different version (And my gulp build concatain all file in a vendor). So i tried to ignore it (like this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18245394/ignore-in-bowers-bower-json)) :

```
"bootstrap-tour": {
      "main": [
        "build/css/bootstrap-tour.css",
        "build/js/bootstrap-tour.js"
      ],
      "ignore":[
        "build/css/bootstrap-tour-standalone.css",
        "build/js/bootstrap-tour-standalone.js"
      ]
    },
```

But i didn't have boostrap-tour anymore.
I tried with only

```
"bootstrap-tour": {
      "main": [
        "build/css/bootstrap-tour.css",
        "build/js/bootstrap-tour.js"
      ]
    }
```

But like this standalone is present
How can i do ?
Thanks

## EDIT

No one can help ?

Comment: Sounds like It might be better if you alter your gulp build process to only gather the vendor files you need rather then grab all the files. Could you post your gulp process?

Comment: I posted it :) Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Here is my gulpfile :

i use : gulp build

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp'),
    rev = require('gulp-rev'),
    templateCache = require('gulp-angular-templatecache'),
    htmlmin = require('gulp-htmlmin'),
    imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
    ngConstant = require('gulp-ng-constant'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    eslint = require('gulp-eslint'),
    del = require('del'),
    runSequence = require('run-sequence'),
    browserSync = require('browser-sync'),
    KarmaServer = require('karma').Server,
    plumber = require('gulp-plumber'),
    changed = require('gulp-changed'),
    gulpIf = require('gulp-if');

var handleErrors = require('./gulp/handle-errors'),
    serve = require('./gulp/serve'),
    util = require('./gulp/utils'),
    copy = require('./gulp/copy'),
    inject = require('./gulp/inject'),
    build = require('./gulp/build');

var config = require('./gulp/config');

gulp.task('clean', function () {
    return del([config.dist], { dot: true });
});

gulp.task('copy', ['copy:i18n', 'copy:fonts', 'copy:common']);

gulp.task('copy:i18n', copy.i18n);

gulp.task('copy:languages', copy.languages);

gulp.task('copy:fonts', copy.fonts);

gulp.task('copy:common', copy.common);

gulp.task('copy:swagger', copy.swagger);

gulp.task('copy:images', copy.images);

gulp.task('images', function () {
    return gulp.src(config.app + 'content/images/**')
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: handleErrors}))
        .pipe(changed(config.dist + 'content/images'))
        .pipe(imagemin({optimizationLevel: 5, progressive: true, interlaced: true}))
        .pipe(rev())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dist + 'content/images'))
        .pipe(rev.manifest(config.revManifest, {
            base: config.dist,
            merge: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dist))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}));
});


gulp.task('styles', [], function () {
    return gulp.src(config.app + 'content/css')
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}));
});

gulp.task('inject', function() {
    runSequence('inject:dep', 'inject:app');
});

gulp.task('inject:dep', ['inject:test', 'inject:vendor']);

gulp.task('inject:app', inject.app);

gulp.task('inject:vendor', inject.vendor);

gulp.task('inject:test', inject.test);

gulp.task('inject:troubleshoot', inject.troubleshoot);

gulp.task('assets:prod', ['images', 'styles', 'html', 'copy:swagger', 'copy:images'], build);

gulp.task('html', function () {
    return gulp.src(config.app + 'app/**/*.html')
        .pipe(htmlmin({collapseWhitespace: true}))
        .pipe(templateCache({
            module: 'gamingBoostApp',
            root: 'app/',
            moduleSystem: 'IIFE'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.tmp));
});

gulp.task('ngconstant:dev', function () {
    return ngConstant({
        name: 'gamingBoostApp',
        constants: {
            VERSION: util.parseVersion(),
            DEBUG_INFO_ENABLED: true
        },
        template: config.constantTemplate,
        stream: true
    })
    .pipe(rename('app.constants.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.app + 'app/'));
});

gulp.task('ngconstant:prod', function () {
    return ngConstant({
        name: 'gamingBoostApp',
        constants: {
            VERSION: util.parseVersion(),
            DEBUG_INFO_ENABLED: false
        },
        template: config.constantTemplate,
        stream: true
    })
    .pipe(rename('app.constants.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.app + 'app/'));
});

// check app for eslint errors
gulp.task('eslint', function () {
    return gulp.src(['gulpfile.js', config.app + 'app/**/*.js'])
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: handleErrors}))
        .pipe(eslint())
        .pipe(eslint.format())
        .pipe(eslint.failOnError());
});

// check app for eslint errors anf fix some of them
gulp.task('eslint:fix', function () {
    return gulp.src(config.app + 'app/**/*.js')
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: handleErrors}))
        .pipe(eslint({
            fix: true
        }))
        .pipe(eslint.format())
        .pipe(gulpIf(util.isLintFixed, gulp.dest(config.app + 'app')));
});

gulp.task('test', ['inject:test', 'ngconstant:dev'], function (done) {
    new KarmaServer({
        configFile: __dirname + '/' + config.test + 'karma.conf.js',
        singleRun: true
    }, done).start();
});


gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch('bower.json', ['install']);
    gulp.watch(['gulpfile.js', 'pom.xml'], ['ngconstant:dev']);
    gulp.watch(config.app + 'content/css/**/*.css', ['styles']);
    gulp.watch(config.app + 'content/images/**', ['images']);
    gulp.watch(config.app + 'app/**/*.js', ['inject:app']);
    gulp.watch([config.app + '*.html', config.app + 'app/**', config.app + 'i18n/**']).on('change', browserSync.reload);
});

gulp.task('install', function () {
    runSequence(['inject:dep', 'ngconstant:dev'], 'copy:languages', 'inject:app', 'inject:troubleshoot');
});

gulp.task('serve', ['install'], serve);

gulp.task('build', ['clean'], function (cb) {
    runSequence(['copy', 'inject:vendor', 'ngconstant:prod', 'copy:languages'], 'inject:app', 'inject:troubleshoot', 'assets:prod', cb);
});

gulp.task('default', ['serve']);
```